# Elasticsearch for completion suggester spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

Hi EveryOne I am new to elasticsearch I want to have a text box for auto completion with the help of  elasticsearch and spring mvc.
I found something on this link on stack over flow.

link : [ElasticSearch completion suggester with Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137479/elasticsearch-completion-suggester-with-java-api)

But enable to create mapping.

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin() .indices().prepareCreate("your_index_name"); 
XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject("your_type_name").st‌​artObject("propertie‌​s").startObject("you‌​r_completion_field")‌​.field("type", "completion").endObject().endObject() .endObject().endObject(); 
createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping("yoru_index_name", 
mappingBuilder); createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

### or

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = ElasticsearchUtil.trannsportClient().admin().indices().prepareCreate("mapping");
XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = jsonBuilder()
            .startObject("users").startObject("properties")
            .startObject("content").field("type", "string").endObject()
            .startObject("search").field("type", "completion").endObject()
            .endObject().endObject();
 createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping("mapping", mappingBuilder); 
 createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

### I want something like this:

```
   "mappings": {
    "article": {
    "properties": {
    "content": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "completion_suggest": {
    "type": "completion"}
   }
 }
}
```

### Or if you can give me fresh code for elasticsearch completion suggester with spring mvc That would be great.

I am using elasticsearch Version:6.1.0 and org.elasticsearch.client transport client version 5.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with elasticsearch you should use same version of java client library as the elasticsearch server. so first update your library version to `6.1.0`.

and then try to follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.1/java-admin-indices.html#java-admin-indices-create-index as suggested by official documentation.